# Tabular display of images

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am very new in Iphone development.
I have a requirement to display images in a tabular form [row column wise].

```
---------------------------------------

| Img1 img2 img3 img4 |

| Img6 img7 img8 img9 |

---------------------------------------
```

Will you please inform me the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.
Suhas.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for multi column grid table view layout , where you can define each and every row and column.

you can check this tutorial for Drawing a Grid in a iPhone UITableView – Tabular Cell Data

http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html
http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a UIScrollView for this. Set the contentSize accordingly to your needs.